# Facebook Login in Django Backend with big Frontend separation.

Tags: python, django, facebook, backend

I'm trying to make a login with Facebook.

What I want is to create and endpoint and use it as I use the "standard" email login endpoint, since I need a big separation between the backend and the frontend. 
I think it should be easy to do it, but I don't know how to do it.

I read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow?locale=en_US) and when I use the Url in the browser, it works properly and I get the token in the response Url. But, it happens always on the frontend side.

I tried many tutorials [this one](https://artandlogic.com/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/) is an example, and it works, but I'm the backend, I'm not allowed to have something like that, as the frontend is written in Django too.

So, I don't know how should be the workflow when you're just the Backend, I don't know what the Frontend developers wait from me because the authentication happens actually on the frontend side.

And I'm a little bit lost.

Maybe someone had the same problem as Backend and could help me, at least tell me, how the workflow backend - frontend should be.

Comment: So your frontend and backend need "a big separation between" them, but you're still using Django for both? Now I'm a bit lost

Comment: have you considered Facebook JavaScript SDK?

Comment: I don't use Django for the Frontend. I'm not the Frontend developer, that was just for testing. They use iOS and Android. I don't have anything to do with the Frontend I just give "Endpoints" that's the problem. And that's the same for JavaScript SDK, I don't have anything to do with the Frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook JavaScript/Android/iOs SDKs lets the client to authenticate the users. Once the user is authenticated with facebook, your clients can send the `accessToken` through a `HTTP POST` over https.

This is what I have done in a similar situation,

## At backend,

Create API endpoint to authenticate user by validating their `accessToken`,

#### **`POST /auth/`**

Use this endpoint to verify the `accessToken` sent by the client. The token should be validated calling Facebook services with your app secret. Once done validating, return a response as a JSON detailing the status of the authentication and user identification details if successful.

on the request,

- body should contain `accessToken` as a key/or a header
- `Content-Type` header should be `application/json`
- any additional expected headers must be validated

on the request try to include

- status of the operation
- user identification detail if operation is success
- a JWT or some sorta token to identify the user which users can include in `Authorization` header, so that you can validate the request just buy validating the token against User. Set an expiry as the `accessToken` if `JWT` is expired, refresh `accessToken` at client side and validate again.

## At Frontend.

Let the client do the following to authenticate themselves.

- send `accessToken` to `/auth` as a POST request.
- if authentication status is success, let them store the JWT in locally and use it on the upcoming requests.

at backend on upcoming calls,

- if token is expired or tampered, redirect client to authenticate with Facebook again.
- on logging out of user, delete the token from client.

So for the frontend developers,
**Document your API properly and share it with them**

Comment: I use too JWT, do you generate a different token with JWT than the Facebook Token?

Comment: JWT tokens can be signed and it is easy to validate JWT than Facebook token as for validating Facebook token you need to call Facebook service.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Got it .